# How do I get a Line6 UX1 soundcard to work?

Tags: drivers, sound, soundcard

I own a Line6 UX1 soundcard and I would like to make it work for Ubuntu.
I have followed the instructions [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-a-line6-guitarport-or-toneport-ux1-or-gx.html) and it worked.

But at some point I upgraded my kernel version (not sure what `uname -a` prints but it's related) and it stopped working.

Here's what `uname -a` prints:

> Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-29-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 11 20:52:10 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I figured out that maybe it's installed per version so I used `svn update` and hit `make` again. My guess was right as it copied the relevant files to the new version's folder.
I restarted and still nothing.
Should I revert to an older version? Or is there a solution here?

Answer (score 2):

Install dkms package. After that all your drivers will be rebuilt every time you update your kernel.

Comment: @Asmerito: Should I just type apt-get install dkms? Also, what do I do with the current situation?

Comment: @Asmerito: It's already installed and up to date. What's next?

Comment: hmm it has no dkms.config file. How do I make one?

Comment: I really have no idea about dkms.config. dkms will compile every driver for new vesion of kernel automatically on boot. Maybe your source code must  be in /usr/src folder? Try to find more where dkms search for source code. 
http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Mantis_with_DKMS might help

Comment: @Asmerito: Well you have to configure it in order for it to work. dkms ignores everything that doesn't have dkms.config

Comment: This can help also:http://blog.rtg.in.ua/2008/11/madwifi-hal-dkms-mini-how-to.html

Comment: In /usr/share/doc/dkms-<version>/ is a sample conf file.